# storing thousands of files on google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am making an app on google app engine where users will upload files. So total files may reach thousands. Will the cloud storage be able to efficiently retrive those files on demand? I am using only a single bucket.

Comment: Is it possible to create a directory structure within a bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is no limit on the number of files in a bucket and the number of files in a bucket has no impact on the performance of cloud storage.

You cannot create subdirectories in buckets but object names can include "/" forward slashes so you can mimick directory structures.

Answer (score 1):

I have a single directory in GCS that has over 15,000 files. The performance is excellent. GCS doesn't seem to suffer from the usual file system lag when too many files are in a directory.